# How to return data from the controller using InertiaJS

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

**This is my ProductController**

```
public function index()
{
  return Product::all();
}
```

I'm looking a way to return this method from an Inertia request to my Vue component, This is the way I tried this,

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
  return Inertia::render('App', [ProductController::class, 'index']);
});
```

**And here is my Vue component (Not the exact one the way I'm trying to get the data)**

```
<template>

</template>

<script>
props: {
  index: Array,
},
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, you can pass the list of your products to your component doing:

```php
public function index()
{
  return Inertia::render('App', [
    'products' => Product::all()
  ]);
}
```

Doc: https://inertiajs.com/responses

Then declare your route like:

```php
Route::get('/products', [ProductController::class, 'index']);
```

This will create a `/products` route that will point to the index action of your controller that will return the list of products to your component.

And in your component, you can access the products:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    {{ products.length }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
props: {
  products: Array,
},
</script>
```

Comment: Your idea is great but this will only apply to the App page.

Comment: @BelugaB69 It's not my idea, it's the way it works. You can do this with any page. Just create a new page (component) and specify the name or path if you have created subfolders in the first argument of the `render` method. You create as many routes and controllers as you need.